# No se pueden editar etiquetas de preguntas sin añadir 6 caracteres al cuerpo como mínimo

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas, ediciones-sugeridas

Como se ve en la imagen siguiente este error se muestra cuando se intenta editar una pregunta y no se agregan 6 caracteres o más en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Pero lo considero un bug en los casos en que se quieren editar solamente las etiquetas de esa pregunta; en estos casos este mensaje no debería salir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reporto esto porque se me han dado varios casos en los que no he podido editar preguntas que tienen mal puesta las etiquetas o que le falta alguna. He intentado editar las etiquetas de una pregunta y no he podido porque me sale dicho error, mientras que mi edición en esos casos no se ha tratado de añadir caracteres, sino de cambiar etiquetas solamente.

Por otra parte, he visto que otros usuarios han editado luego esas mismas preguntas que yo no he podido, agregándole "negritas" y "cursivas" innecesarias al cuerpo de la pregunta para llegar a los 6 caracteres y eso tampoco es correcto, por tanto sugiero lo siguiente:

Que detecte si en la edición se están modificando o agregando etiquetas; y si es así, entonces no se muestre el error que se ve en la imagen. Por supuesto, la edición de la pregunta sólo se aceptará si la edición de la etiqueta tiene sentido.

Comment: Además de las etiquetas, no modificaste el cuerpo de la publicación en pocos caracteres?

Comment: No, no había nada que agregar al cuerpo, mi intención era solamente quitar la etiqueta SQL que no tenía relación con la pregunta y agregar HTML y PHP que eran las que les correspondían. Ya de todas formas alguien lo hizo, pero agregó negritas y cursivas innecesarias para poder editar la pregunta. Pero lo que quiero decir es que no debería ser así desde mi punto de vista, se podría hacer algo como lo que digo en el último párrafo de esta pregunta, que es que el sistema detecte cuando la edición se trate solamente de un cambio de etiqueta y en este caso no exija agregar caracteres

Comment: así es cómo funciona. Cuando sólo se editan las etiquetas, no debería aparecer esa advertencia, y debería permitirte la edición. Si podés reproducir el error, sin editar el cuerpo de la pregunta en lo más mínimo, te recomendaría que agregues todo el detalle posible y reetiquetes esta pregunta como [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: @Mariano así lo hice

Comment: No sé si lo recordarás @Adriana, pero ¿por casualidad la etiqueta tenía tildes en el nombre? (Pregunto por otros errores que se relacionan a tildes en etiquetas)

Comment: Yo creo que la restricción se debe a privilegios. Yo puede hacer edición, por ejemplo, puedo quitar una etiqueta como [tag:php] sin problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por el reporte de este bug.  Investigaré lo que podemos hacer para eliminarlo.